# reload a tab based on selector of previous tab

Tags: javascript, php, tabs, reload

I have a problem not sure how to reload a tab based on a selector in the previous tab.

My code for tab is here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#addpropertypanel1" data-toggle="tab">
            <s1>
                <?php echo Jtext::_( 'ADDRESS');?>
            </s1>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#addpropertypanel2" data-toggle="tab">
            <s1>
                <?php echo Jtext::_( 'GENERAL_INFORMATION');?>
            </s1>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#addpropertypanel3" data-toggle="tab">
            <s1>
                <?php echo Jtext::_( 'OTHER_INFORMATION');?>
            </s1>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#addpropertypanel4" data-toggle="tab">
            <s1>
                <?php echo Jtext::_( 'PHOTOS');?>
            </s1>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my GENERAL INFORMATION Tab, there is a category selector to choose a value. This value chosen will affect the content in Tab OTHER INFORMATION.

I would like to know how can i reload OTHER INFORMATION tab only with information based on the selection chosen in GENERAL INFORMATION.

I am a very inexperience programmer, any assistance is very much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

You can use JavaScript (jQuery) to manipulate the links based on their contents.

See this example: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVxNy/)**

```
var myValue = '';

switch( $('a[href=#addpropertypanel2]').text() ) {  
    // put here your all cases that Jtext::_( 'GENERAL_INFORMATION') can offer
    case "abc":
        myValue = "new value 1";
        break;
    case "def":
        myValue = "new value 2";
        break;
    case "GENERAL_INFORMATION": // just for example manipulation
        myValue = "new value 3";
        break;
}

$('a[href=#addpropertypanel3]').text( myValue );
```

---

**PHP**

You could also manipulate it with PHP by switching the output of `Jtext::_( 'GENERAL_INFORMATION')` before inserting it to the links. So insert the value that you want after the switch instead of `Jtext::_( 'OTHER_INFORMATION')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind AJAX events for loading the desired information from PHP and injecting it into the tab.

A little step by step tutorial:

1. **The data source**:
   In PHP you have to write some code, that echos the desired data when calling a new URL (something like `http://www.your_domain.com/get_info`) depending on POST or GET parameter. For this example I'd like to use GET parameter, which would result to `http://www.your_domain.com/get_info?address_id=1` (`1` is just an example id value)
2. **The container**:
   Then in the HTML add a container into the tab for your data. It needs an id, so you can use it with JavaScript. Something like `<li><a href="#addpropertypanel2" data-toggle="tab"><s1><div id="general_information"></div></s1></a></li>`
3. **The event**: Now you've got a data source (the new URL) and a destination (the container in the tab of your HTML), all you need to do is use some JavaScript to add the data from the source into the destination. But before you can bind an event to your `<select>`, you should  give it an id, to ease the binding (something like `<select id="addresses_select">`). I would highly recommend using jQuery for the binding, because it's easy for new developers and it just works in all browsers. (To add jQuery to your page, simply add the following snippet into the `<head>` of your HTML: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`). When using jQuery you can use the following snippet for retrieving the desired data and injecting it into your HTML container.

jQuery event snippet:

```
$('#addresses_select').change(function(){
  var selected_address_id = this.value;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/get_info?address_id=" + selected_address_id,
    success: function(desired_data_from_php) {
      $("#general_information").html("<p>" + desired_data_from_php + "</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

That should be all.

Good luck :-)

**PS**: in the following fiddle you can see how the event for the `<select>` works: http://jsfiddle.net/LyLHL/